# Install Angular into existing project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I realize that this used to be accomplished with `ng init` but that no longer exists.  It is also possible to run `ng new` from one level up the directory tree and target the folder of your extant project, but that will overwrite `package.json` thereby wiping out all the dependencies you already put in for yourself.  Is there any way to accomplish the same as `ng new`, but in an already-extant project?

Answer (score 1):

Well I see two immediates solutions :

**1) Run ng-new in another project / folder**

Then just copy paste the angular dependencies into your own package.json and run

```
npm i
```

**2) Make a temporary duplicata of your dependencies**

Then just run ng-new in your own project and put your dependencies back.

Those two solutions are not perfect, and I don't claim they are, but they are a **5 seconds-thinking solutions** and sometimes, having the same result in less time can worth as much as the perfect solution.

Comment: Admittedly not perfect, but a good suggestion indeed. Someone should make an  node module just to perform this task lol :P